# Point only one page onto another server

Tags: migrations

Is it possible to send traffic to another server with different NS only for a specific page? 
I would like to have only one page of my website pointing to an external server - Unbounce.
Wordpress has [a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/unbounce/) that allows a page on Unbounce servers to integrate with the same domain of an existing CMS website.

For example:

```
www.mydomain.com --> Drupal
www.mydomain.com/page1 --> Drupal
www.mydomain.com/page2 --> Drupal
www.mydomain.com/all-pages --> Drupal
www.mydomain.com/only-one-page --> Unbounce
```

if that's possible, i would like to have the homepage, pointing to an Unbounce server and the rest of the pages to remain on Drupal.

thank you

Comment: I'm also checking same thing but didn't get good idea. Anyone have any idea for this ?

Comment: @AjayGadhavana i haven't found anything yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this requires a reverse proxy so start your searches there.. It isn't really a Drupal thing. I can get this sort of thing working with nginx but I'm not good enough at it to give an actual answer. If you're on shared hosting, it's impossible I think.